# Script loader not working in webpack 2

Tags: webpack, loader, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I'm upgrading to webpack 2 and had this file to load all vendors:

```
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/timestamp-event.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/underscore-1.6.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/underscore.string-2.3.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/underscore.inflection.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/underscore.translit.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/underscore.util.operators-0.1.4.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/underscore.function.combinators-0.1.4.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/moment-2.7.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/spark-md5.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/lawnchair-0.6.1-custom.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/local-storage-emitter.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/jquery-2.0.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone-1.1.2.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone.marionette-1.8.8.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone.middleware-0.0.1p1.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone.rel-0.2.5.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone.turbo-where-1.2.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone.virtual-collection-0.6.9.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/backbone.grouped-collection-0.1.2.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/textarea-helper-0.3.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/elasticize-2.5.0.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/bootstrap-tooltip-2.3.1.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/bootstrap-tooltip-extension-0.0.5.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/bootstrap-popover-2.3.1.js');
require('!!script-loader!./vendor/bootstrap-popover-clickover-1.0.js');
// ... and more ...
```

This way they were available globally, so for example I could use `_` for underscore anywhere in the code.

Now, in webpack 2 + webpack dev server, none of these are available globally, is there something I'm missing?

**My ENV:**

- webpack v2.4.1
- webpack-dev-server v2.4.5
- script-loader v0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 2 allows **just 1 trailing "`!`"** in `require` statements.

From [Webpack docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#via-require):

> It's possible to overwrite any loaders in the configuration by
>   prefixing the entire rule with !.

Have you tried removing them?

Comment: I tried, however this is really weird. I have two entry points, core and vendor. If I put the code above into core one, it works, if I put it into vendor one, it doesn't!